# Cannot access environment variable on mac from System.getenv() in build.gradle

Tags: java, macos, gradle, groovy

So I need to customized dependencies in gradle based on a environment variable.
For that I created a variable using the `export ENV=test` command.
I do a printenv and I see that as listed in the console on mac.
However , when I do a System.getenv() from the build.gradle file it is not visble.
Suggestions ?

Answer (score 6):

I had similar issue.
In my case the gradle daemon cached environment variables.
For reset the cache I stopped demon gradle.

You can use next command for it.

```
gradle --status
gradle --stop

./gradlew --status
./gradlew --stop
```

`status` show runnabled demons.
if you don't have, you can to try to stop by using wrapper gradle.

And after it during next start gradle have my env variables.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact error. I tried [Gleb Belyaev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69538619/8832537), but it did not work. For me, as simple as restarting the IDE resolved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I am using Gradle 6.3 as a deamon.
The following works perfectly for me:

```
println System.getenv()
```

Answer (score -1):

To get your environment with the key of EXAMPLE, you can do the following:

```
println System.getenv("EXAMPLE")
```

it works for gradle with version 5.5 as well.

Comment: I am doing that. When i do a println of Syste.getEnv I can see all variables but not the one I just created.

Comment: How you run the program? Do you use IntelliJ? Or you're building directly from CLI?

Comment: tried doing both. So the build.gradle is there and I do a gradlew clean build